# Error appears when changing ArrayAdapter<String> to custom Adapter that extends ArrayAdapter<String>

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

Basically what I have is a fragment which displays a ListView. It currently uses an ArrayAdapter. However I'm trying to extend the ArrayAdapter to make my own custom adapter. Then, when I change the code to use my new adapter, the following error appears:

"No enclosing instance of type MyActivity is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type MyActivity (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of MyActivity)."

Here's the code: Note this is all nested within MyActivity

```
public static class MyFragment extends ListFragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public MyFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fixed_tab, container, false);

        // Temporarily get the content from an array
        String [] values = new String[] { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4" };

        /******** This has no error as it is, but if I change it to CustomListAdapter, it shows the error ********/
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.workout_row, R.id.workout_name, values); 
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}

private class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    String[] list;
    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, String[] array) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, array);
        list = array;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        cb.setTag(position);

        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    // TBI
                }

            }
        });

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: create `CustomListAdapter` class inside `MyFragment` class or as separate class instead of create two classes in same file

Comment: also your getView implementation is wrong

Comment: Ok I'm trying this but findViewById will not work if the adapter is nested in the fragment. Also, elaborate how my getView is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate .java file as CustomListAdapter.java and copy your adapter code there

In constructor of CustomListAdapter

```
 LayoutInflater inflater;
 public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        int textViewResourceId, String[] array) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, array);
    list = array;
    inflater = LayoutInlfater.from(context); 
}
```

In `getView`

```
View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.workout_row,parent,null); // inflate custom layout
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
// use the inflated view object to initialize checkbox
```

Also it is better to use a ViewHolder pattern

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Answer (score 0):

your adapter needs to be inside your `MyFragment` class, currently it is outside your class brackets